# reuse "sum(table_column) as x"

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a problem with an SQL query.

```
SELECT SUM(table_colum) AS value, SUM(value * 3) AS value2 FROM table;
```

You need to know this is a short representation of my whole query.

The error:

```
Unknown column 'value' in 'field list'
```

Is there a way to reuse `value` in another `SUM()`?

Comment: I can't quite picture the results that you want. `SUM(table_column)` is already a single value, since you have neither an explicit `GROUP BY` nor an implicit one; so, what does it mean to compute the `SUM` *of* it?

Comment: @ruakh there is a complex calculation, but that has nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do:

```
SELECT SUM(table_colum) AS value, SUM(SUM(table_colum) * 3) AS value2 FROM table;
```

Internally, the server will only do the `SUM(table_colum)` calculation once and use the result twice.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could write

```
SELECT value, SUM(value * 3) AS value2
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(table_column) AS value
           FROM table
       ) AS t
;
```

But as I mentioned in a comment above, I'm not sure what you would want this for. `SUM(table_column)` is just a single value, so the `SUM` of it is just the same value. So you'd get the same result by writing:

```
SELECT value, value * 3 AS value2
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(table_column) AS value
           FROM table
       ) AS t
;
```

without the second `SUM`.